# Designing a purely reactive circuit with the following requirements

Tags: power, impedance, magnetics, reactance

how would you design a purely reactive circuit with:
Infinite impedance in f = 0 Hz and f = 800 Hz
Zero impedance in f = 5000 Hz and 11000 Hz
At 7000 Hz, has a reactance of 181.85 Ohms

How to proceed here using MATLAB

Comment: Can you be a little clearer about the impedances and the frequencies - I got 0Hz(infinity) and 800Hz(zero) but I'm not sure what you want for the other frequencies and is 181.85 ohms capacitive or inductive impedance i.e. - or + j185.85 ohms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember doing this kind of thing about 3 years back, though I've forgotten the specifics. You might want to look up \$1^{st}\$ and \$2^{nd}\$ Cauer forms, which will give you the connection and basis for calculating the values of inductance and capacitance required in the circuit.

The network equations will be in the complex frequency domain (equations(s) in the \$s\$-domain also called \$Laplace \space \text{domain}\$). These equations can be easily implemented in Simulink (a "toolbox" in Matlab) using integrators and differentiators.

Comment: Are you sure that's the only information given? It would have been much simpler if the form of the transfer function was given, or better still the transfer function itself.